# How Simulate Right Leg Driver

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential

I am having trouble simulating Right Leg Driver in an amplifying circuit of eeg signals.

The schematic of the circuit:

[image]

The instrumental amplifier circuit has a gain of about 2 and **E1** have 10m amplitude and 10Hz.Then the output of the circuit should be:
**10mV * 2 = +/- 20mV**

When I use the RLD circuit, the output **I_E1** is:

[image]

However, when I do not use the RLD circuit, the output **I_E1** is:

[image]

The output with RLD is correct?
The simulation is like that or am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have DC feedback in the RLD circuit.  Add a 200k resistor in feedback and see what happens.  The resistor on the output is current limiting, not for gain.

Comment: I did not understand, where should I add the 200k resistor?

Comment: @EdDc Parallel to C4